# How to configure oracle database in codeigniter  config php

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am trying to configure oracle db as my second_db in my codeigniter database.php which is config , Can anyone tell me how to configure oracle db

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oracle";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oci8";
```